# Client cert label `ibmwebspheremq<userid>` for domain user

Tags: .net, security, certificate, ibm-mq

If the client connected to the WebSphere MQ server is using a domain account, say `box1\user1`, then is the client's cert label: `ibmwebspheremquser1` or `ibmwebspheremqbox1\user1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The user ID specified would be `user1` giving a label of `ibmwebspheremquser1` in this case.  However, that depends on the version of WMQ used and in some cases the behavior differs and can be changed as described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21245474). Note also that the answer applies to clients other than Java/JMS clients such as the C client and the .Net client.  The behavior of the Java and JMS clients uses Java standard cert resolution.

So if it's not working based on this, it would be necessary to update your question with details of the WMQ client type and version.

Comment: We are connecting to the mq using .net mq client v7.0. Would like to check with you if the the label ibmwebspheremquser1 still applied? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. In MQ .NET client, SSL is supported in Unmanaged mode where the .NET layer invokes MQ C Client. Hence the label would be as described above by T.Rob.

Comment: Thank you to both T.Rob and Shashi :)